# Unable to escape space in a string java

Tags: java, sql-server, string

Here is my code:

```
Assume metaname = "hello world";
String metaname = metaname.replaceAll("/", "\\/").replaceAll(" ", "\\  ");
adding metaname as parameter to query.

FreeformQuery query = new FreeformQuery("select * from table where metaname =" +metaname);
```

This is giving me the error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'world'.

Comment: Please post the entire code ... how come you got sql error for a string operation

Comment: Why would you do this instead of using a `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: `replace(" ", "\\ ")`

Comment: did you try String str ="'hello world'";  ? with a single quotes inside double quote

Comment: I'm not experienced with SQL Server, but are you sure you need to escape *spaces*??

Comment: yeah i need to. what else should i do to resolve the lssue?           http://stackoverflow.com/users/1553851/shmosel

Comment: @msv: `String metaname = metaname.replace("/", "\\/").replace(" ", "\\ ");`

Comment: it didn't work @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Why do you think spaces need to be escaped? What issue were you having?

Answer (score 0):

Try 2 backslashes "\\ " as a backslash its self needs to be escaped

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by putting metaname inside single quotes:
FreeformQuery query = new FreeformQuery("select * from table where metaname = '" +metaname+ "'");